# Incrementing a value progressively on each item

Tags: jq

So i have this Grafana dashboard that i'm making up using `jq` and different files. The problem i end up with is that when you export the json produced by Grafana, it will export it the way it sees it currently. Example:

```
[
  {
    "gridPos": {
      "h": 1,
      "w": 24,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 22
    },
    "panels": []
  },
  {
    "gridPos": {
      "h": 1,
      "w": 24,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 43
    },
    "panels": []
  },
  {
    "gridPos": {
      "h": 1,
      "w": 24,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 17
    },
    "panels": []
  }
]
```

But the problem is that the grid positions need to be properly incremented (the Y's) so that when you reload the Grafana dashboards, the panels nested under row panels get set to their proper locations. If you have a sub panel that has a `gridPos.y` that is lower than the row panel's `gridPos.y` then it will appear in a weird location.

I tried using reduce and foreach but i'm not super good with these constructs yet. For example, i tried this:

```
[
    1 as $currentY |
    foreach .[] as $item (
        [];
        (. + [$item * {"gridPos": {"y": ($currentY + 1)}}]); 
        . | last
    )
]
```

But i can't figure out how to increment `$currentY` within the loop to achieve proper incrementation. The objective would be to nest a second foreach/reduce to continue setting and incrementing $currentY in all panels and sub panels.

Can you help? Thanks!

Note: I know i should use `reduce` when using `.|last`, this was just the last try. Don't point that out, i want guidance on how to increment `$currentY` in the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

With your *existing* approach as such, you need to reference the `y` field in each `$item` processed and increment its value, rather than the predefined value of `$currentY`, i.e.

```
[
    1 as $currentY |
    foreach .[] as $item (
        [];
        (. + [$item * {"gridPos": {"y": ($currentY + $item.gridPos.y )}}]); 
        last
    )
]
```

which again could be written as

```
[
    1 as $currentY |
    foreach .[] as $item (
        [];
        (. + [ $item | .gridPos.y += $currentY ]); 
        last
    )
]
```

which again could be written with a simple `walk` expression

```
1 as $currentY |
  walk ( if type == "object" and has("gridPos") then .gridPos.y +=  $currentY else . end )
```

Comment: Looks good but how does $currentY get updated then? Cause here you are simply adding 1 all the time no?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin At this point am not sure your what your requirement is. Do you want to increment it for each iteration? How should the y value be incremented then?>

Comment: Just by 1, like a for loop, i want to reset the gridPos.y and resequence it

Comment: Just so you know, i ended up doing it with nodejs to make it work but i would have liked to use a JQ only solution to streamline everything into a single docker container instead of two different containers.